# How to extract an element in an array if the filter element is 2 levels down

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

My `ListInputSecurityGroup` task returns this json:

```json
{
  "output": [
    {
      "Arn": "arn:aws:medialive:eu-north-1:xxx:inputSecurityGroup:1977625",
      "Id": "1977625",
      "Inputs": [],
      "State": "IDLE",
      "Tags": {},
      "WhitelistRules": [
        {
          "Cidr": "5.5.5.5/32"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Arn": "arn:aws:medialive:eu-north-1:xxx:inputSecurityGroup:5411101",
      "Id": "5411101",
      "Inputs": [],
      "State": "IDLE",
      "Tags": {
        "use": "some_other_use"
      },
      "WhitelistRules": [
        {
          "Cidr": "1.1.1.1/0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Arn": "arn:aws:medialive:eu-north-1:xxx:inputSecurityGroup:825926",
      "Id": "825926",
      "Inputs": [
        "4011716"
      ],
      "State": "IN_USE",
      "Tags": {
        "use": "for_rtmp_pipeline"
      },
      "WhitelistRules": [
        {
          "Cidr": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to use `OutputPath` to extract the `InputSecurityGroup` with the tag `{use:for_rtmp_pipeline}`. According to this [JSONPath tester](https://jsonpath.com/) this expression works `$.output[?(@.Tags.use == for_rtmp_pipeline)]` and it returns the 3rd element in this array. But when used in the StepFunction itself, or in the Data Flow Simulator, it doesn't return anything. Is this a limitation of the JSONPath engine in AWS, or is there a different syntaxis? How can I extract the one element I want?

Note that in the tester the searched string should be in quotes, while in AWS there's no need for quotes.

Comment: can you check if it works without the `_` in AWS?

Comment: @AkshayG you mean the underscores in for_rtmp_pipeline?